# Sharepoint: get number of sites in a collection

Tags: sharepoint, web-crawler, moss

I'm trying to get the total count of subsites created in a very large Sharepoint collection. Please note, I don't have direct access to the server.

- Is there any native sharepoint feature I'm missing that will provide a site count?
- Is there a webservice that can crawl the collection? (we have google analitics)
- Are there any other options short of running a powershell script on the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the 'Webs' Web Service - you can invoke it by putting /_vti_bin/webs.asmx on the end of your site URL. It has a method [GetAllSubWebCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getallsubwebcollection.aspx).

The only gotcha is that you will get filtered results based on the user being used to access the web service. For example, if you have a site collection that has a sub-web created for HR, Business, Management, Sales and IT - but your account only has access to the HR and Sales site - you will only get results back for the HR and Sales sites.

You may also find the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) jQuery library helpful as it has wrappers for most of the web services and can make calling them from a client much less painful.

*Note: These web services exist for the 2007 and 2010 editions of SharePoint. You didn't mention a specific version but hopefully it is one of these two.*

Comment: Thanks! I get to a page with a list of services available but how do I invoke them? And sorry I am using a split 2010/2007 environment ('10 back, '07 front)